# Setting WPF Window DataContext to RelativeSource Self

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I set the Window's DataContext to `this` in the constructor *as well as* to `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` in XAML then I can see that the DataContext refers to the correct object instance (i.e. the MainWindow) by placing a break point in the code-behind's Loaded event. However, the Window's child element exampleButton's Command binding is null. The assertion fails.

When I remove the XAML DataContext setting (and rely on the constructor setting only) then exampleButton's Command uses the DataContext correctly.

Why is exampleButton's Command bound to null in the XAML scenario?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Example"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        x:Name="mainWindow"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Loaded="mainWindow_Loaded">
    <Button x:Name="exampleButton" Command="{Binding Path=ExampleCommand}" Content="Click"/>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ICommand ExampleCommand { get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ExampleCommand = new DelegateCommand(x => { throw new ApplicationException(); });
    }

    private void mainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Assert(mainWindow == this);
        Debug.Assert(mainWindow.DataContext == this);
        Debug.Assert(exampleButton.DataContext == this);
        Debug.Assert(exampleButton.Command == ExampleCommand); //<-- FAIL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is exampleButton's Command bound to null in the XAML scenario?

Because the `ExampleCommand` property actually has a value of null by the time the `InitializeComponent()` method returns and the `DataContext` property is set.

If you want to set a property to a new value after this, the class must implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface for the target property to get refreshed automatically:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ExampleCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(x => { throw new ApplicationException(); });
    }

    private ICommand _exampleCommand;
    public ICommand ExampleCommand
    {
        get { return _exampleCommand; }
        set { _exampleCommand = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private void mainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Assert(exampleButton.DataContext == this);
        Debug.Assert(exampleButton.Command == ExampleCommand); //<-- FAIL
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: So, it's because: in the XAML scenario the Window.DataContext *_is not_* null so the Button.Command *_is_* bound to the null value of ExampleCommand (because ExampleCommand hasn't been constructed yet), but in the Code Behind scenario, the Window.DataContext *_is_* null and so Button.Command *_is not*_ bound until Window.DataContext is assigned and then ExampleCommand is assigned, and then it works *without* implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Thank you. It's pretty confusing, if I'm honest.

Answer (score 4):

Set `ExampleCommand` and `DataContext` before `InitializeComponent`:

```
 DataContext = this;
 ExampleCommand = new DelegateCommand(x => { throw new ApplicationException(); });
 InitializeComponent();
```

Also note that there is no difference between using `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` or `DataContext = this;`, if you set datacontext before initializecomponent.

Comment: Thanks @Ron, I'm still a bit unclear on the exact answer to my question but your answer highlights the importance of the call to InitializeComponent().

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Of course, I think there is no need for a ``INotifyPropertyChanged`` in your situation, because you are going to set the command once. Please read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6531588/5615980) for more information.